# Generate link for particular place without route name

Tags: symfony

I want to have a link to web/uploads/documents

Normally I get link as

```
{{ path('name in route.yml') }}
```

But there is no link name for web/uploads/documents

How can acess there in twig file??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just typ `web/uploads/documents`? E.g.

```
<a href="/web/uploads/documents">{{ foovar }}</a>
```

Comment: I see...... Until now,I always tried such as '../../uploads/documents','../uploads/documents' depending on how deep  directories my application is in,.....